# How do make application thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, task

I have a class, whose responsibility is to connect to the device and perform some activities.

- This class have a private static `IDictionary` member entitled `localDicttionary`- This is used to create mapping between `deviceid` and it's `name`
- This class have a method `StartWorkItem`, whose responsibility is to check if `deviceid` already exists in the dictionary, else add it to the dictionary.

  ```
  class DeviceManager
  {
    bool isBusy;
    private IDictionary<string, string> localDicttionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();         

    public bool StartWorkItem()
    {
     if (!LocalDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
     {
          LocalDictionary.Add(id, stationName);
     }
     //do some action which makes  isBusy=true/false               
    }

     public static IDictionary<string, string> LocalDictionary
     {
      get
      {
          return workstaionmapperDictionary;
      }
      set
      {
          workstaionmapperDictionary = value;
      }
    }


    public bool IsBusy()
    {
       return isBusy;
    } 
   }
  ```

We have a queue, which has a list of device details to be processed one by one

```
   workQueue = new Queue<WorkItem>();
```

Now, I have created instances of `DeviceManager` to process this `workQueue`. 3 instances created so that if one of the `manager` is busy then processing can be handed over to next instance.

```
        dManager= new DeviceManager[3];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < dManager.Count(); ++ii)
        {
            dManager[ii] = new DeviceManager(this);
        }

         for (int ii = 0; ii < dManager.Count(); ++ii)
         {
            if (dManager[ii].IsBusy())
                   continue;// go to next manager and assign him a task

            if (workQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                WorkItem item = workQueue.Dequeue();
                if (!dManager[ii].StartWorkItem(item))
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Question is, Code is working fine, but I believe it's not thread safe. How can I make it thread safe?

**Updates**

Word `thread safe` is confusing. The requirement is: We have 1000+ devices on network and we like to connect every device and update it's one of the `property`. we have `com` library which is used for updating the property. connecting to device sometime fails or succeed depends on device power (on/off). so we want to continue processing `next` device in the collection even though `last` processing takes more time or fails.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193730/discussion-on-question-by-kudlatiger-how-do-make-application-thread-safe).

Comment: How do work items relate to the devices?

Comment: work item has all device details like name, IP, model etc.  In "StartWorkItem" i will try to conect to the device using device SDK. It will fire "connection success" or "failed" events where it makes "IsBusy" variable true/false